# Input file fire twice in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, input, dojo, internet-explorer-11

There is a simple input file:

```
<form id="uploadForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="getCSVFile" method="post">
    <input type="file" class="upload" id="uploadFile" name="file" />
    <input type="text" name="campaignId" style="display:none" data-dojo-attach-point="campaignIdInputValue"/>                                   
</form>
```

But when I click to input file it opens file select window, I choose file or  click cancel and every time it close file select window and open the same new. It happened only for IE.

Even if I remove all code except

```
<input type="file"  />
```

I have same problem. Also I should specify that I use it with Dojo framework.

Comment: Consider including the `getCSVFile` javascript method in your question. This may hold the answer?

Comment: I have  deleted action but it still apears(